# Class property gets null as a value

Tags: php

I have two classes:

DI

```
namespace engine\DI;

class DI
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $container = [];

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->container[$key] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($key)
    {
        return $this->has($key);
    }

    public function has($key)
    {
        return $this->container[$key] ?? null;
    }
}
```

and Cms

```
namespace engine;

use engine\DI\DI;

class Cms
{
    /**
     * @var DI
     */
    private $di;
    public $router;

    /**
     * @param $di
     */

    public function __construct($di)
    {
        $this->di = $di;
        $this->router = $this->di->get('router');
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //$this->router->add('home', '/', 'HomeController:index');
        print_r($this->router);
    }
}
```

As you can see in `Cms`, I put a `$router`'s value in constructor and for some reason it remains null. The interesting part is when I `print_r($this->di->get('router'))` it works just fine and returns proper value. Even more, when I call method by this value directly (like `$this->di->get('router')->add();`) it also works wonders, so the value itself is clearly not null. What could be the reason of this?

Here are two additional files where the value comes from:

Provider:

```
namespace engine\service\router;

use engine\service\AbstractProvider;
use engine\core\router\Router;

class Provider extends AbstractProvider
{
    public string $service_name = 'router';

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    function init()
    {
        $router = new Router('cms/');
        $this->di->set($this->service_name, $router);
    }
```

Bootstrap:

```
use engine\Cms;
use engine\DI\DI;

try {
    $di = new DI();
    $cms = new Cms($di);

    $services = require 'config/services.php'; //stores an array with providers

    foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
        $provider = new $service($di);
        $provider->init();
    }

    $cms->run();
} catch (\ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the value for router?  As the value is stored at the start of building the Cms object, if it's set after that object is created, the new value won't be used.

Comment: I don't completely understand, I set it in constructor, isn't it supposed to assign new value to a property at first place?

Comment: In your constructor, you get the value from the DI container using `$this->di->get('router')`, so this value is already expected to be set.  So my comment was about where the value in the DI class is set.

Comment: I've added two additional files, take a look, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the additional info, it seems like what **Nigel Ren** has pointed in the comments is in fact the issue.

You should have it like this:

```
try {
    $di = new DI();

    $services = require 'config/services.php'; //stores an array with providers

    foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
        $provider = new $service($di);
        $provider->init();
    }

    $cms = new Cms($di); // creating the Cms object after di is initialized
    $cms->run();
} catch (\ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that :

```
    public function __construct($di)
    {
        $this->di = new $di();
        $this->router = $this->di->get('router');
    }
```

Comment: I think ```$di``` property is being assigned correctly as I can access all ```DI``` methods

Comment: They are injecting the `DI` instance, not the name so this would most likely throw a fatal. And if they create a new instance of the DI, then `router` will _definitely_ not be set.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
$di = new DI();

$services = require 'config/services.php';

foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
    $provider = new $service($di);
    $provider->init();
}

  $cms = new Cms($di);
  $cms->run();
 } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```